# How to make echo compatible with read in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, pipe, echo

I tried this:

```
qs@BF:~$ echo aaa | read c
qs@BF:~$ echo $c
```

It gives nothing, which means $c is an empty macro.

But why the following one works:

```
qs@BF:~$ cat trim.hs | read cc
qs@BF:~$ echo $cc
import qualified Data.Text as T
```

It correctly gives the first line of trim.hs

There seams to be an exception when `echo` piped with `read`.
Am I right? Could you help me to make `echo` compatible with `read`? Please.

Comment: `echo aaa | read -r c` works. I wonder why in this case.

Comment: So does `read c <<<aaa` which is the preferable method in bash.

Comment: @TomFenech Yes, the here-string works, but why? If you try `echo aaa | hd` you see that there is a newline at the end. It's the same as `hd <<< 'aaa'`

Comment: @hek2mgl I'm not sure! Incidentally, the version with `-r` didn't work for me either (I thought it did but `c` was already set)

Comment: Damn! It just *seemed* to work because `$c` was already set!! :)

Comment: it seems that   `echo aaa | read c`  doesnt work here:

Comment: @torosFanny, `echo $cc` shows something for the same reason as hek2mgl's comment: you would have had a pre-existing value for that variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of these "work"

```
echo aaa | read c
cat trim.hs | read cc
```

In bash, commands in a pipeline are all executed in subshells. So, the `read` command sets the variable `c` *in a subshell*, but then that subshell exits and its environment disappears

To demonstrate, let's query the value of `$c` in the subshell using a grouping construct:

```
unset c
echo 123 | { read c; echo in subshell: ">$c<"; }
echo in parent: ">$c<"
```

outputs

```
in subshell: >123<
in parent: ><
```

bash does have a setting to allow the **last** command in a pipeline to run in the **current** shell:

```
set +m               # job control must be disabled
shopt -s lastpipe    # enable the option
unset d
echo 456 | read d
echo ">$d<"
```

```
>456<
```

Comment: running the last command of a pipeline in the current shell is the default behaviour of ksh93

Answer (score 2):

I think the underlying problem here is subshells that `read` is run in. These won't (always) propagate values to your invocation.

From the [POSIX `read` standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/read.html) it outlines how using `read` within subshells will not be visible to the caller:

> If it is called in a subshell or separate utility execution environment, such as one of the following:
>
> ```
> (read foo)
> nohup read ...
> find . -exec read ... \;
> ```
>
> it shall not affect the shell variables in the caller's environment.

And noting in [these shell tips](http://www.etalabs.net/sh_tricks.html):

> POSIX allows any or all commands in a pipeline to be run in subshells, and which command (if any) runs in the main shell varies greatly between implementations — in particular Bash and ksh differ here. The standard idiom for overcoming this problem is to use a here document:
>
> ```
> IFS= read var << EOF
> $(foo)
> EOF
> ```